# How to check if "Java is outdated" bar is visible on Google Chrome?

Tags: java, security, google-chrome, deployment, applet

My website has a java applet that must run for complete functionallity. The problem is that some users have an outdated Java version, which makes Chrome show that annoying bar on top along with not running the applet at all.

How can I check if the outdated bar is visible, so I can show an arrow pointing to the 'Run this time' button and make sure all users with an old Java version get to run the applet? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I check if the outdated bar is visible..

Probably by deploying the applet using the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) & specifying a Java version of greater than or equal to 'latest know, secure (for the moment) Java'.

Then it shouldn't appear at all.

### Update

> It's a 3D display of molecules with some extra info. It's essential as the website is pretty much about that only

I think that seals it.  Launch the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, **desktop integration**, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

That 'desktop integration' includes desktop shortcuts (like for Star Zoom Animation and JotPad below).

[image]

Once the user is launching the app. from the desktop icon, we can be sure they won't be seeing any Chrome warning.

Comment: Will the applet run if the version is lower?

Comment: @esauvisky - should you allow it to run?  Is it a responsible thing to do?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sure, I've read it, but my knowledge in Java is very sparse and I haven't understand it that well =(

Comment: @StephenC Yeah, I always run it. It's harmless, don't worry =)

Comment: The script would prompt the user to update.  What exactly is this applet that is 'vital' to your site?  No site should have to rely on a Java applet for any core part of the functionality.  Or if so, it is probably better to have a desktop app. based around a `JFrame`, consuming the web service.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's a 3D display of molecules with some extra info. It's essential as the website is pretty much about that only. :P The problem with having a desktop app is that it would "untie" with the rest of the page: wont be that seamless...

Comment: @esauvisky - You miss my point.  Given the plethora of security bugs that have recently been detected and fixed in Java plugins, is it responsible to not encourage / force people to upgrade their out of date / insecure Java installations?  I don't think so!  Frankly, I don't think you should be using applets on your website ... at all.